# Параметры в скрипт передать в командной строке

Tags: python, функции

Как переделать этот код так,чтобы параметры в скрипт передавались в командной строке

```
def makeRandomData(recordNumber, region, mistakeNumber):
        print(recordNumber + region + mistakeNumber)


makeRandomData(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: `import sys; print(sys.argv)`.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов Я не понимаю, как это корректно связать с кодом, который я предоставила (начала изучать этот язык только сегодня утром)

Comment: Вставьте это в самое начало кода и позапускайте с параметрами из командной строки.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов а какой синтаксис запуска с параметрами. Я уже перепробовала столько вариантов. Один из них `makeRandomData('1','2','3',)`

Comment: `python file.py param1 param2 param3 ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys
def makeRandomData(recordNumber, region, mistakeNumber):
        print(recordNumber + region + mistakeNumber)

try:
    recordNumber = int(sys.argv[1])
    region = int(sys.argv[2])
    mistakeNumber = int(sys.argv[3])

    makeRandomData(recordNumber, region, mistakeNumber)

except:
    raise ValueError("No required attributes")
```